# Use of unresolved identifier 'UIScreen'; did you mean 'NSScreen'? DynamicTypes works fine on iOS, but it doesn't on macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Using DynamicTypes works fine in iOS, but the same code is not working in macOS, how can I Implement it?

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/305Fh.png)

```
 switch UIScreen.main.traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory {
        case .extraSmall:
            return 1
        case .small:
            return 2
        case .medium:
            return 3
        case .large:
            return 4
        case .extraLarge:
            return 5
        case .extraExtraLarge:
            return 6
        case .extraExtraExtraLarge:
            return 7
        case .accessibilityMedium:
            return 8
        case .accessibilityLarge:
            return 9
        case .accessibilityExtraLarge:
            return 10
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge:
            return 11
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge:
            return 12
        default:
            return 0
        }
```

Comment: If you’re building a macOS app it’s obvious that UIScreen is not found because it belongs to UIKit which is an iOS only framework

Comment: The IDE is correct, on macOS it is `NSScreen`. And please post any code as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: ok @luk2302 I tried with NSScreen, but it doesn't work, do you know how to Implement it?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio do you know how to implement on macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIScreen` isn't available on macOS, which uses `NSScreen`. But, more to the point of your question, Dynamic Type is an iOS, watchOS and tvOS feature; it's not built into macOS.

Mac applications often provide user options to increase/decrease font size or change fonts, and that's likely what you'll want to do as well.

Comment: Do you know how to implement it on macOS?

Comment: macOS does not have Dynamic Type support. What is it you want to know how to implement? If you're talking about adding your own options to increase/decrease font size or change fonts in your application, there are lots of examples online. Basically, you provide menu options or controls to alter the text size you're drawing with, or display the font panel and let them specify the exact fonts to use.

But, as far as system-wide Dynamic Type support like on iOS goes, it doesn't exist on macOS.

Comment: In your mac, if you go to Settings -> Displays -> Resolution and select Scaled, I wanna know which scale is selected (Larger, default, shorter) with swift. Do you think is that possible?

Comment: All that does is change the display resolution to some predetermined sizes. If you hold down the option key and click on the "Scaled" button, you can usually see resolutions that can be selected (depends on the Mac).

Comment: You can get the main display resolution from `NSScreen.main.frame.size` or the resolution that most of a window is on by looking at `window.screen.frame.size`. Keep in mind that a Mac may have multiple screens though and the window may span more than one.

Finally, you can get notified of a screen's resolution change by observing the `NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification` notification.